# glob() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve a directory saved from database and open all the images inside that directory. The problem is, when I run the code, the result is "Warning: glob() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\try\test.php on line 5". BTW I'm just starting php and I'm not yet knowledgeable enough on it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my code in test.php

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
$path = 'SELECT directory FROM path WHERE id = 1';

$files = glob($link, $path);
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    echo '<a href="'.$num.'"><img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image" style="width:300px;height:200px;"></a>'."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}
?>
```

And this is the config.php

```
<?php
session_start();
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'sam');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
?>
```

Comment: I believe you're passing a variable that doesn't exist. What's the value of `$link`?

Comment: $link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

Comment: Read deeply about glob function than try your logic http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves the problem.

```
<?php

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sam', 'root', '');

$q= $conn->query("SELECT directory FROM path WHERE id='1'");
$result = $q->fetchColumn();
$path = glob($result);
for ($i=0; $i<count($path); $i++)
{
    $num = $path[$i];
    echo '<a href="'.$num.'"><img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image" style="width:300px;height:200px;"></a>'."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}

?>
```

Successfully retrieved the directory from database and displayed the files inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're misunderstanding the purpose of `glob()` and how to execute MySQL queries using PHP.

`glob()` doesn't execute MySQL queries. `glob()` checks the files in the current directory. Check the link here, http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php.

What you need to do is research how to execute MySQL statements and parse the returned values.

Check out this question, it explains how to use `PDO` to execute MySQL queries: [PDO MYSQL PHP prepare() and execute()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561770/pdo-mysql-php-prepare-and-execute).

And this explains how to retrieve values after executing a PDO query: [return one value from database with mysql php pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928136/return-one-value-from-database-with-mysql-php-pdo#27220180).

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure thing. Would be awesome if you accepted my answer!